# Is a time frame of time of day circular data?

Tags: distributions, circular-statistics

I have data points with time of day. But I only took data between about 6:00 AM and 18:00 PM. If I want to test these data for distribution do I have to take a circular test? Or should I take a non-circular test? Is time of day circular if you cut out a piece of it?

Comment: Since all your results are between 6 and 18, you shouldn't need a circular test. A circular test would apply if you had values like 2359 and 0001, which are actually very close to each other, not 23h58m apart. In your case, you don't cross midnight, so no circular test required.

Comment: Do all the points refer to the same day?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. No, they are not at the same day. Do have any link or source where this is discussed because this is an argument between me and someone else about if circular tests are suitable or not.

Comment: @NickCox days in the year are circular data too? I am an economist so I a not keen to this type of data. I am reading this post with much interest as it is opening a new world in front of me. I think I have a related problem in here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189401/regression-discontinuity-design-on-panel-data-running-variable-is-day-within-y I am really sorry if I am wrong on that. Now, I'll be reading intensively on this topic on stats.exchange. Thank you for making me discover this subject!

Comment: There is no objection to your using circular methods for this kind of data. In practice the substantive results will be similar. A disadvantage of circular methods is that they use concepts that may be new to you or your readership (e.g. mean resultant length or vector strength as a measure of variability; is that familiar?). I am an enthusiastic user of circular methods (e.g for times all around the clock, or directions all around the compass) but for times of day 6 hr to 18 hr I would use conventional methods.

Comment: @NickCox So you say, I can use both but you'd recommend to use non-circular methods?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would say on this information. You tell me: would your audience recognise circular methods? But I don't know what "test these data for distribution" means to you or what your data look like.

Comment: @NickCox Yes, I've done the Rayleigh test with that data. The problem is I would like to check for clustering of a part of that data but the data is not homogeneously taken and so the total data is clustered. We tried to fix that by cutting out the time where no data was taken (18-6) because including night time would create clustering just by missing data (I guess that's a no-go). But even if we exclude the night data the total data is still significantly non-uniform. I would say, I can't make statements about a part of the data if the total data is clustered. What do you think?

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question or starting a new thread. Post data and give details within a question.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192770/is-a-time-frame-of-time-of-day-circular-data