# Which statistical tests are reasonable with this time of day data set?

Tags: statistical-significance, circular-statistics

I'm not really sure which statistical test is appropriate for my data.

**data**: I have behavioral data (being active, resting, eating ...) with a time stamp. Data was taken between 6-18 h and is not homogeneously spread over the time frame. More data points were taken at midday and less in the morning and evening. Have a look at the frequencies of data points per hour in the plots (the white bars represent all of my data).
[image]

**What I want to do**: I want to test if certain behaviors occur more often at a certain part of the day. For example if eating occurs more often in the morning.

**What I did**: I used the Rayleigh test. But with no data overnight data had to be non-uniform. Therefore we cut out the time where no data was taken (18-6) to reduce artificial clustering. But data was still significantly non-uniform (more data point at midday and less in the morning/evening). I think I can't make a statement about clustering over the day of a specific behavior if the total data is not uniform and therefore influences the occurrence of each particular behavior. The results of the Rayleigh test were all pretty similar. All data had it's mean at midday (11-13 h).

In a previous question ([Is a time frame of time of day circular data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192770/is-a-time-frame-of-time-of-day-circular-data)) my assumptions that I can also you non-circular tests were confirmed.

Therefore I'm looking for a statistical test that can tell me if a certain behavior was observed more often at a certain part of the day.

I'd love to hear your thoughts about that.

Edna

Comment: It sounds like the data is very clearly non-uniform already; i.e. if you make a histogram, is it immediately apparent that the data is not uniformly distributed? In a sense, we know a priori that eating will not occur during sleep, so the uniform hypothesis does not seem to be very interesting. 

I think it is not entirely clear what hypothesis you want to test. Do you want to test a specific time, that is, "Does 'eating' occur more at 2pm than 5pm?", or something else? What is the exact question?

Comment: @KeesMulder Thanks for your answer. I added a plot to visualize the situation of my data. So,  you clearly can put a parable over my data. Therefore, my problem is how am I supposed to find any trend or clustering at a part of day if my data shows this midday trend as well? The easiest solution that comes to my mind is to test the medians. So if the eating points are centered around another time of day than the total points.

Comment: To compare means, you could do that with some form of non-parametric ANOVA (ie. Friedman). To compare mean directions, you could apply the Watson-Williams test. They should be applied between the categories of behaviour, not, for example, "eating vs. total". These tests will answer the question "Do the means/mean directions differ between these groups of data?". It's still not really clear to me whether this is the question you want to answer, but it is some interpretation of "any trend or clustering at a part of the day".